# What is the purpose of '/var/lib/dpkg/available' file in Ubuntu/Debian?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, dpkg

What is the role of the `/var/lib/dpkg/available` file in Ubuntu and Debian machines?

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of "How to recreate /var/lib/dpkg/status".  `status` and `available` are different files with (presumably) different purposes.  `status` tracks the status of installed (or partially installed, or to-be-installed) packages.  However, all `man dpkg` says about `available` is the following:  "dpkg keeps its record of available packages in /var/lib/dpkg/available."  However, the man page never explains what it meas for a package to be "available".  So the question is very much unanswered, imo.

Answer (score 1):

Beyond the obvious (a list of currently-available package versions, used by the Debian installers such as [dselect](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2002/10/msg06480.html), dpkg and [apt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/161866/how-to-recreate-var-lib-dpkg-status)), not much.  It's a flat-file database (or cache of one).

Further reading:

- [Chapter 5. The /var Hierarchy](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#PURPOSE31)

Comment: `apt` doesn't use `/var/lib/dpkg/available`, it uses its own caches.

Answer (score 0):

`/var/lib/dpkg/available` is the list of available packages in dpkg-based systems (such as Debian and Ubuntu).

For more info:

```
man dpkg
```