# When is /var/lib/dpkg/status-old created?

Tags: dpkg

I've copied a dpkg-status file backup from /var/backups to /var/lib/dpkg/status, but I would like to restore the status file to what it was before the copy. Will status-old in /var/lib/dpkg/status contain a copy of the status file before it was overwritten?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the date when you modified `/var/lib/dpkg/status`, to the modification date of `/var/lib/dpkg/status-old`, by running the command `ls -lt /var/lib/dpkg/ | grep status-old` this will show you when `/var/lib/dpkg/status-old` was modified last.

Just wanted to add this really nice answer in context to this question:[Why you should not mess with /var/lib/ files.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/161872/237568)

Comment: it shows the same time as the status file. Does this mean the status file was backed-up to status-old before being overwritten? Or is status-old now the same as the status file?

Comment: Seems like it, don't you have the backup of the status file that worked in `/var/backups/`?

Comment: Thanks. Yes I saw some tips from that answer. I compared the backup with the true status file and there were differences. The status file and status old match after copying status-old to status. I am worried the differences were just recent packages I installed today meaning status-old was not a back-up. I will look more into it.

Comment: @rigger12 did you determine what the difference between `status` and `status-old` were?